# Проблемы в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вот мой код

```
number = input("Введите ваше значение: ")
while number != '+' or '-':
    number = input("Введите ваше значение: ")

while number:
    if number == '+':
        plus()
        break

    elif number == '-':
        minus()
        break

    elif number == '*':
        multiply()
        break

numberS = input("Желаете продолжить?\n"
                  "Если да, то нажмите 1, если нет, то любую клавишу")
```

Мне нужно что если пользователь не вводит `+ или -` то выскакивает окно что мол не верно. Но если уже он ввел верно то далее его пропускает в зависимости от того что он выбрал. И после как уже функция выполнилась. То идёт вопрос о том что будете ли что-то делать. И как всё это сделать на постоянном повторе пока пользователь уже сам не нажмет на кнопку 4(позже будет добавлено) чтобы выйти из программы

Comment: `while not number in ['+',  '-']:`

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4):

```
count = 0

values = []
operation = None

operations = {
    '-': lambda a, b: a - b,
    '+': lambda a, b: a + b,
    '*': lambda a, b: a * b
}


while True:
    data = input("Введите ваше значение:" if count % 2 == 0 else "Введите операцию:")

    if count % 2 == 0:
        if data in operations:
            print("Ошибка! Требуется ввести значение")
            continue

        values.append(int(data))

        if len(values) > 1 and operation is not None:
            res = operations[operation](values[-2], values[-1])
            print("результат:", res)

    if count % 2 == 1:
        if data not in operations:
            print("Ошибка! Требуется ввести операцию")
            continue

        operation = data

    count += 1
```